# How do i find out the disabled receiver's intent-filter?

Tags: android, intentfilter

for example

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>    
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

An app has a receiver,and it set `android:enabled="true"`.

I tried the code below,but it does not work.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = mPackageManager.queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
```

but the BootReceiver is not in the resolveInfoList.

And i also have tried these code.

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = mPackageManager.getPackageInfo(applicationInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_RECEIVERS);
ActivityInfo[] receivers = packageInfo.receivers;
```

Some of the receivers are null.

So how do I find out the disabled receiver's intent-filter?

Answer (score 0):

My bad.

I find a flag (GET_DISABLED_COMPONENTS) just now.

So i can use this code

```
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = mPackageManager.queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, PackageManager.GET_DISABLED_COMPONENTS);
```

Now it works.